# Displaying graphs

Tags: android, graph

What would be the best way to display a graph in android? Something like the image displayed below. You might recognize it. Its from battery monitor widget.

[image]

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I'm wondering how this particular graph was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open source project called Android Battery Dog which you can access on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/andbatdog/). It shows you how a graph can be drawn and how to append the usage details to the graph.